# Syntax for strings list with unrepr mode

Tags: python, configobj

It works with digit list; I tried with single and double quote without success.

```
from configobj import ConfigObj, ConfigObjError
from io import StringIO

specs= """\
Number= [6, 8]
Electric= [`battery`, `solar_panel`]
"""

car1="""\
Number= 6
Electric= battery
"""

car2= """\
Number= 8
Electric= solar_panel
"""

class Processing():
    def __init__(self, car):
        super().__init__()
        try:
            ConfigObj(StringIO(car), configspec= StringIO(specs), unrepr= True)
        except ConfigObjError as e:
            print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Processing(car1)
    Processing(car2)
```

Result:

```
Parse error from unrepr-ing value at line 2.  
Parse error from unrepr-ing value at line 2.
```

Comment: I don't think the backslash `\\` is required as triple quotes are doc string.

Comment: Is just for line number is clear for human, thanks. I use triple quotes for multiline variable.

Answer (score 0):

With the unrepr set to true, you must indicate that Electric is given a string. So, you must write:

```
car1="""\
Number= 6
Electric= 'battery'
"""

car2= """\
Number= 8
Electric= 'solar_panel'
"""
```